# If $X$ is complete, then every subset of $X$ that is closed and totally bounded is also compact. Does the converse hold?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ denote a metric space.

Supposing every subset of $X$ that is closed and totally bounded is also compact, is $X$ necessarily complete?

*What I've got so far.* Assume every $X$ subset of $X$ that is closed and totally bounded is also compact, and consider a Cauchy sequence $a : \omega \rightarrow X.$ Then the image of $a$ (call it $A$) is totally bounded. (However, $A$ is not necessarily closed; now what?)

Comment: Consider the closure of the image.

Comment: @nik, thanks. So okay, consider the closure of $A$, call it $B$. Then $B$ is both closed and totally bounded; hence compact. Thus $I=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty (\mathrm{cl} \circ \mathrm{im})(a \restriction [n,\infty))$ is non-empty... Any ideas how to finish the proof from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, consider the image of the cauchy sequence, $A$, which is totally bounded by the cauchy property.  So it's closure, $B$, is totally bounded and closed, so compact by hypothesis.

To finish the proof just use sequential compactness.  You know a subsequence converges, but it is a basic fact (easy to prove) that if a subsequence of a cauchy sequence converges then the cauchy sequence converges.